# Nginx and PHP5 timeout error 504

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

Hi I'm getting a timeout error (504 -gateway timeout) with Nginx and PHP5-fast cgi. I'm not sure why this is happening but when I restart php-fpm everything seems to work fine.

How can I debug this?

I have no errors in dmesg

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
fastcgi_index index.php;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP-FPM pool for the various timeout settings.